# Need help plotting a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have 2 columns - one that has a number (Section) and the other one that says if its `good` or `bad` in `r`. 
Here is a sample data

```r
df <- data.frame(G_or_B = c("Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good"), Section = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2, 3,3) )
```

I need a ggplot (barplot) that says for every section, how many `good`s and how many `bad`s it has in r and also displays the number of Goods and Bads in the bar. I'm new to r, but can understand pre-existing code good enough.

I have the code for ggplot that plots the bargraph but can't get it to display numbers. When I try the below code, I get the bar filled with "good" or "bad" instead of the count,

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Section, fill = G_or_B) )+ 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

The end result, ideally would have this ggplot, along with the number of Goods and Bads displayed on the bar

[Plot after trying above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deuoN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The method you tried will work if you count your data first:

```
library(dplyr)
df_count = count(df, G_or_B, Section)
ggplot(df_count, aes(x = Section, y = n, fill = G_or_B) )+ 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]